# String matches across multiple lines in text using Regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this sample string

```
ABC : 5149427501\nDEF : 4168170001\nGHI : RC81020329801823\nJKL : 24938699\nMNO : 941580078
```

I want to extract the value corresponding to strings `ABC` and `JKL` using regex.

So the pattern should return `5149427501` as match for `ABC` and `24938699` as match for `JKL`.

I have been trying to formulate the regex and code for that but it is not working.

```java
String line = "ABC : 5149427501\nDEF : 4168170001\nGHI : RC81020329801823\nJKL : 24938699\nMNO : 941580078";
String pattern = "^\\s*(ABC|JKL)\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(4) );

} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

But it is not working.

I am beginner in regex. Can you please suggest how to find the pattern in the String?

Comment: Your pattern works, but I think you have to use `while (m.find()) {` and get the value of group 1 and 2. See https://ideone.com/cBocRG

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You need flag DOTALL and not flag MULTILINE. You also need to drop the *start of line* metacharacter, i.e. `^` and you need to use `while` instead of `if` to keep searching for the next occurrence of your pattern. Lastly, your *regex* only contains two groups.

Compare your code with the following.

```
String line = "ABC : 5149427501\nDEF : 4168170001\nGHI : RC81020329801823\nJKL : 24938699\nMNO : 941580078";
String pattern = "\\s*(ABC|JKL)\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
boolean found = false;
while (m.find()) {
    found = true;
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

The output produced by the above code is:

```
Found value: ABC
Found value: 5149427501
Found value: JKL
Found value: 24938699
```

Comment: Why do you need DOTALL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your string line is a json string。if so, I think the best practise is using jackson to resolve your problem。

You can see here my code here
https://github.com/onemaomao/java-common-mistakes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/geekbang/time/questions/stackoverflow/reslove/q2/JacksonUsage.java

Comment: String line = "{\"ABC\":\"5149427501\",\"DEF\":4168170001,\"GHI\":\"RC81020329801823\",\"JKL\":\"24938699\",\"MNO\":\"941580078\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map readValue = mapper.readValue(line, Map.class);
        System.out.println(readValue);
        System.out.println(readValue.get("ABC"));
        System.out.println(readValue.get("JKL"));